# Linux find Bash/Bourne files then add .sh

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a noob but here is my problem.

I have different files in a folder and I need to add .sh to some of those files (only the bash Bourne ones).
Also I'm forced to use File command to know which ones.

I did: `file folder/* | grep 'Bourne' | mv whatever comes here`

File command shows me the types then I pipe them into grep to find the Bash/borne shell ones that I want to rename.

Now here I'm stocked BC I obviously can't pipe them to change their names bc I'm not piping the repertory where they are but the info from File command.

How do I continue?

*I must use File, Xargs and a maximum of three pipes.*

Answer (score 0):

```
file folder/* | awk '/Bourne/{gsub(/:/,"",$1); print $1}' | xargs -i bash -c "echo mv {} {}'.sh'"
```

Remove the `echo` when it looks as if it might to what you want.

What did I do?

Use `awk` instead of grep, that allows you to output only the names of the files that matched 'Bourne' in `file`'s output.

Then feed those names to xargs into a new bash ... `xargs -i` (I know, I know, it's deprecated and I should be using -I"{}" instead, but as long as it works ;)) which makes `{}` the placeholder for the filename passed from `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

just use file and awk:

```
file * |awk -F: '/Bourne/ {system("mv "$1" "$1".sh")}'
```

explanation

```
file * - displays descriptions of the contents of files in the current directory
-F: sets separator to character:
/Bourne/ matches lines containing the word Bourne
system() executes a system command in awk (mv here)
$1 is the first field on the line, which is the name of the file
the characters " are arranged so that awk expands $1 as variables, not as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Piping into a Loop inside a Block of code. It looks a little unwieldy compared to the other answers but the technique is useful to know.

```
file folder/* | awk '/Bourne/ {print $1}' | { while read Fname ; do mv "${Fname%:}" 
"${Fname%:}".sh; done; }
```

**Don't forget** you need that space before the last **}**.

**%** is removing the **:** when it's on the right-side of the file name - you don't want that.